# Uninstalling ArcGIS Desktop 9.2 to install ArcGIS Desktop 9.3?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, installation, arcgis-9.3, windows-7

I had previously installed ArcGIS 9.2. I uninstalled it to install 9.3. but I am getting error:

> ArcGIS Desktop 9.2 exists on your machine. You must uninstall ArcGIS Desktop 9.2 before installing ArcGIS Desktop 9.3

ArcGIS 9.2 does not show up in list of installed programs. I used revo uninstaller to clean the remaining files and registry as well. ArcGIS 9.3 conflict detector does not show any conflicts but still I am not being able to install ArcGIS 9.3. The same package installs in other machines, just not in the machine with 9.2 previously installed. ArcGIS 9.3 license manager is easily installed.

I must use ArcGIS 9.3 as an extension is built on 9.3 and does not work in recent versions. I am using Windows 7 operating system.

Comment: Windows registry corruption is common enough that the solution is common as well -- Reimage the OS and start over.

Comment: Vince's advice is the quickest solution or spend many hours hacking registry (not a good idea if have limited knowledge of it)

Answer (score 5):

I think the best advice that you are likely to get on uninstalling/installing this very old software is [a thread at GeoNet](https://geonet.esri.com/thread/12592).

It mentions precisely the same error message as you are seeing.

Answer (score 1):

ArcGIS 9.2 leaves some entries in the registry. You have to manually remove the entry of ArcGIS in registry. Until those entries are not removed, new installation will lookup those values and if found use them. since they don't match with the new one there will be error. Unfortunately this error is not shown by the software.